# How to import config to a site installed with a profile?

Tags: 8, configuration, installation-profiles

Good day. I’ve installed a profile, made my settings, entered my content, exported config and pushed everything to the repo. Now, when I clone it somewhere else and attempt to install using the config, I get a lot of `these entities need to be deleted first` errors, along with others. Is there an easier way than either going to the UI and deleting the said entities one by one or going with `drush edel <entity>`?

Comment: Please update your post to include one question only.

Comment: Which entitles?